How to resolve gap from shower pan to wall for glue up shower surround?
Newer Homeowner here. Bought this house a year ago and this shower has plagued me with problems. It was originally a closet before being converted by someone with some questionable skills.
Long story short, I pulled off my acrylic shower walls to reglue as they were barely hanging on only to discover this hot mess.
https://imgur.com/a/pkXDfSp
Any suggestions on how to fix the gap from the wall and shower tray? It’s about a 3/8 - 5/8 of a gap in various places where they’ve hammered out the wall to recess the tray. In other words it’s recessed too far. There’s also the obvious vertical gaps all around
Theres been some foundation settlement so nothing is square and I’m going to assume that’s insulation with asbestos in the first picture so I will not be knocking down any walls. The subfloor needs addressing first anyways
I plan on redoing my shower correctly in a couple years so I just need a fix to last me until then.  My biggest concern is the left corner where water pooling has the highest potential
So far as ideas I’ve considered

Closed cell backer rod but not sure if that’s sturdy enough
Cut to fit a piece of wood and Waterproof it

And that’s about it. I’ve read about shower bead but not sure if that would be fitting here
Sorry if this is long but appreciate the help

Not going to tell how to do it half a$$ed. Tear off the wall board and do it right one time.

They certainly made a mess of that "Upgrade".
For a temporary solution here is a thought.

Come up off the shower tray edge about 6" and snap a level line on the wall. Straighten out that old wall board and straighten out that jagged cut edge

Go get some Du-Rock cement backer board or Hardie synthetic backer board and cut a 6" rip to fill in the void you just cut.

Skim seams and bottom edge with fast setting hydraulic cement and/or ceramic tile thin-set mortar.

Once dry, paint with elastomeric waterproof coating.

Reinstall shower wall panels, caulk bottom with silicone.



